# Get array index inside its element on array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, syntax

What I want is to write something like this:

```
const list = [
    {name: 'apple'},
    {column_index: MAGICAL_METHOD_GET_ARRAY_INDEX(), name: 'banana'}
}
```

and to have

```
list: [
    {name: 'apple'}, 
    {column_index: 1, name: 'banana'}
]
```

I think it's not possible without creating a counter, or a function which will implement `MAGICAL_METHOD_GET_ARRAY_INDEX`, but maybe I'm wrong? As time goes, javascript gets new features. Maybe there's already such a way?

Please also don't mention `map`, `reduce`, or any other post-initialization processing. I'm asking about built-in syntax features.

Comment: `map()` is your friend, the optional second argument to the callback is the index

Comment: @Dexygen Of course I know that. I want exactly what I ask for.

Comment: @Mikhaill Balcer It's trivial once you remove the unnecessary requirement that the method call needs to be made inside  the literal.  And an approach other than `map()` is to wrap everything in an IIFE.

Comment: @Mikhaill you're asking for a sugar syntax that does not exists in JS, so if you don't care about the result but only about how the code "looks" the answer is no, is not possible what you're asking: you want to refer to a variable before it's even initialized, that's not possible, period. And even if it would exists a function like that it would perform worst than actual `map` (since it would be a function call per element).

Comment: @Dexygen the problem is, I have to use the index in literal definition, but only in certain elements. For example, in formatting function for the fifth column of a table - yet there's no way for the function to know it's in the fifth column other than hardcoding "5" in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter class.

```js
class Counter {
  #val
  constructor(init=0) {
    init = parseInt(init);
    if (Number.isNaN(init)) init = 0;
    this.#val = init;
  }
  get next() {
    return this.#val++;
  }
  set(n) {
    n = parseInt(n);
    if (Number.isNaN(n)) return false;
    this.#val = n;
    return true;
  }
  reset() {
    this.#val = 0;
  }
}

const counter = new Counter(0);
const list = [
    {id: counter.next, name: 'apple'},
    {id: counter.next, name: 'banana'}
]

console.log(list);
```

If you don't want to use a class, the only other option is to keep track of a counter variable outside of your function and increment it each time you run the function.

```js
let counter = 0;
let getArrayIndex = () => counter++;

const list = [
    {id: getArrayIndex(), name: 'apple'},
    {id: getArrayIndex(), name: 'banana'}
];

console.log(list);
```

If you want to do this multiple times, you may want to consider a function like this:

```js
let resetCounter = () => { counter = 0; };
```

Comment: I'm asking about syntax features. Of course I know about `map`.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer there is no way to get the current index of an element in an array before it is initialized. I removed the thing about `map`, but your only options here are to either use `map` or to use an incredibly hacky workaround like the ones in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access to any property of `list` since it's not defined yet. What you can do is split the process in two part using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as @Dexygen mention in his comment:

```js
const list = ["apple", "banana"].map((name, id) => ({id, name}));

console.log(list);
```

Comment: OP specifically said not to mention map.

Comment: It was a post edit of the question, the original question did not have such constraint and therefore I replied based on that (see the edit). Also, I added a comment to the question based on the new edit he made.